# realloc - memory leak

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I got some C code:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t len;
    size_t alloclen;
    char *buf;
} str;

void strnappnd(str **s, const char *buf, size_t n) {

    if ((*s)->len + n >= (*s)->alloclen) {
        size_t nalloclen = (*s)->len + n + 1;
        void *tmp = realloc((*s)->buf, nalloclen);
        if (!tmp) {
            printf("failure");
            exit(-1);
        }
        (*s)->buf = tmp;
        (*s)->alloclen = nalloclen;
    }
    memccpy((*s)->buf + (*s)->len, buf, '\0', n);
    (*s)->len += n;
    (*s)->buf[(*s)->len] = '\0';
}

void strfree(str **s) {
    free((*s)->buf);
    free(*s);
    *s = NULL;
}
```

Apparently, the strnappnd leaks at the realloc line. Why?

Comment: @user282635 Do you eventually free `(*s)->buf` after the final realloc?

Comment: @aix: I think the use of realloc means you don't need to free the buffer.

Comment: @Nick I mean after the final `realloc`.

Comment: How are you detecting the leaks?

Comment: @aix: Ah ok, you mean once this function has returned - sometime in the future.

Comment: **The important thing** is that the string is not appended when there is already enough space.

Comment: @Nick Precisely. I've clarified my earlier comment.

Comment: Three points: 1) function names cannot start with "str", that's a reserved name space; 2) consider growing the buffer by more than 1 byte, if this is for general-purpose, to amortise the cost of multiple appends better; 3) as @pmg said, there seems to be code lacking for the case where the buffer is large enough. Factor it out of the realloc()-path.

Comment: @unwind, @aix, @pmg, @Nick: I updated my code. I always free the str structs with the `strfree()` function. It still leaks.

Comment: You don't need the double indirection `**s` in `strnappnd` as you never change the pointer itself only the structure it points to. This will allow to remove all the unecessary `(*p)` indirections.

Comment: How do you detect the leak? With what tool? I had once (don't remember the name) a tool that lost track of `realloced` pointers when the pointer changed. `realloc` can return the old pointer or a new one and that tool thought the old pointer was then lost. It was a bug of the tool, not of the code. Your code looks ok so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
void f() {
  str *s = (str *)malloc(sizeof(str));
  s->len = 5;
  s->alloclen = 5;
  s->buf = strdup("Hello");
  strnappend(&s, " World!", 7);
  free(s); /* courtesy of Eric */
}
```

If you had something like that, the memory allocated by `realloc()` would leak as `f()` is left.

Comment: And the memory allocated by `malloc()` as well.

Comment: I think a better example would be where an instance of `str` is allocated on the stack.

Comment: @Erik: I think as far as memory checkers go, the memory allocated by the `malloc()` call would be associated with the `realloc()` call. So technically, as far as memory checkers go, only `realloc()` leaked (again, I'm just guessing). I believe this is because `realloc()` may not be able to just extend the already allocated memory chunk in size due to memory fragmentation. Instead, it may have to release the memory and allocate a totally new chunk of the requested size.

Comment: @Frerich: I'm talking about the malloc in your first line :)

Comment: @Frerich: No, the realloc is called on `s->buf` rather than `s` itself.

Comment: @Erik, @Nick: Oh, oops - yes of course, you are right. I somehow thought you referred to the `malloc()` done by the `strdup()` call. In fact, I only used `malloc` here after I realized that `strnappend` takes a `str **` instead of a `str *` - and after seeing the `strfree` function in the original question, I guess that's what user282635 does as well. I fixed the code sample now.

Comment: I `free(s->buf)` as well, though. Take a look at my `strfree()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote

```
(*s)->buf = realloc((*s)->buf, nalloclen)
```

that would be a memory leak, because if `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`, you lose the `(*s)->buf` pointer, which is still pointing to allocated memory.

Since you exit on failure it's not a problem, but maybe your static analyser ignores the `exit`?

Comment: @user282635 – What is telling you that the `realloc` leaks? Some sort of static analyser? Valgrind?

Comment: No, I run the code (pretty much just what I posted) in a loop and the memory usage grows and grows...

Comment: @user282635 – You should post the rest of the program because the memory handling in these two functions looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like this mtrace said "No memory leaks"

```
char *strnappnd(str **s, const char *buf, size_t n) {
    ...
    return (*s)->buf;
}
void strfree(str *s){
    free(s->buf);
    free(s);
}
```

using the sample code given by Frerich

```
void f() {
  str *s = (str *)malloc(sizeof(str));
  s->len = 5;
  s->alloclen = 5;
  s->buf = strdup("Hello");
  s->buf = strnappend(&s, " World!", 7);
  strfree(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create strfree() function and it is not used inside the code.
The memory need to be free always, if it is not used.

```
if (!tmp) {
    printf("failure");
    if (!(*s) && !((*s)->buf))
       strfree(&(*s));
    exit(-1);
}
```

Looking strfree(), looks as you reserved memory for *s too in somewhere.
Do the same before your code finish.

```
if (!(*s) && !((*s)->buf))
   strfree(&(*s));
```